# Selenium project halted with error after some time of running in Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, raspberry-pi

I developed an app on raspberry pi arm device to scrape data from web interface. For tat purpose I benefited from selenium library in python and as browser I used iceweasel. I successfully run my app for two days. Then it stopped giving the error below :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/Downloads/ModbusTermostat/ekon.py", line 28, in 
>       termostatlar = driver.find_elements_by_id("evntemperature")   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 281, in find_elements_by_id
>       return self.find_elements(by=By.ID, value=id_)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 778, in find_elements
>       'value': value})['value']   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette

Here are the information about installed Firefoxx :

> {u'rotatable': False, u'browserVersion': u'45.6.0',
>   u'takesScreenshot': True, u'acceptSslCerts': False, u'appBuildId':
>   u'20161213204132', u'XULappId':
>   u'{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}', u'javascriptEnabled': True,
>   u'raisesAccessibilityExceptions': False, u'specificationLevel': u'1',
>   u'platform': u'LINUX', u'browserName': u'Firefox', u'version': u'',
>   u'proxy': {}, u'marionette': True, u'device': u'desktop',
>   u'takesElementScreenshot': True, u'platformName': u'Linux',
>   u'platformVersion': u'4.4.26-v7+'}

and Selenium version is :

> 3.0.2

I suspect that It is some kind of version mismatch. But Still I could not figure out the problem.

Comment: will never work if don't install `geckodriver`.And need upgrade to  from '45.6.0' to '47.+.+.+'

Comment: how can I upgrade iceweasel to 47?